# Anyone can help me on how to limit the type into absent on my search result. this is my query

Tags: php

```
$query = "SELECT Full_Name, Yearsection, Course_No, Type, Date_Time FROM classroomattendance WHERE Type=Absent CONCAT (`Full_Name` , `Yearsection` , Type) LIKE '%".$valuetosearch."%' ";
$search_result = filterTable($query);
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably want an AND between Type=Absent and CONCAT

Comment: Thanks :) @user744621